# Symfony 3.1 PSR-6 Caching Settings

Tags: php, caching, doctrine-orm, symfony, symfony-3.1

Config.yml:

```
cache:
    app: cache.adapter.doctrine
    system: cache.adapter.doctrine
    default_doctrine_provider: ~
    default_psr6_provider: ~
    default_redis_provider: "redis://localhost:6379"
```

Symfony 3.1 support doctrine cache, but you do not have enough documentation.

Cache Component: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache.html
Supported drives: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache/cache_pools.html
Symfony Integration: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-1-cache-component

default_doctrine_provider: ? What do I enter as Provider

Answer (score 2):

You can pass to `default_doctrine_provider` either a Redis connection DSN (for example "redis://127.0.0.1:6379") or ID of a service which implements `Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\AdapterInterface`

You can have a look at already implemented adapters [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/master/src/Symfony/Component/Cache/Adapter)

Answer (score 0):

The provider basically is the original `doctrine_cache` provider you configured. Let's say you use the `DoctrineCacheBundle` and your provider name is `my_apc_cache` that means the container has the following service:

```
$myCache = $this->container->get('doctrine_cache.providers.my_apc_cache');
```

You could also define an alias, then it is even easier.

Take a look at the example at: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineCacheBundle/usage.html#service-aliases